# Push values in array to match a specific format

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have an api giving me values that I am trying to push into my array. My array is structured like this

```
this.rolesArr = [
  { label: 'Admin', value: '1' },
  { label: 'Manager', value: '2' },
  { label: 'Recruiter', value: '3' },
  { label: 'Operational', value: '4' }
];
```

The data I receive is like this

```
{1: "System Admin", 2: "Internal Account Manager", 3: "CAT Manager", 4: "HR Admin", 5: "HR Manager", 6: "HR Recruiter", 7: "Candidate", 8: "Operations administrator"}
```

How can I push it to the array to match the structure?

I am trying this but am stuck

```
for(let i = 0; i < roles.roles.length; i++) {
  this.rolesArr.push([ { label: , value: '1' }])
}
```

Comment: Post your try on this and everyone will post a lot of alternatives.

Comment: expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get key-value pair as an array and then use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to generate your array.

```js
let data = {1: "System Admin", 2: "Internal Account Manager", 3: "CAT Manager", 4: "HR Admin", 5: "HR Manager", 6: "HR Recruiter", 7: "Candidate", 8: "Operations administrator"};

let res = Object.entries(data).map(([value, label])=>({ label, value }))

console.log(res)
```

To add these values into an existing array use [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) with [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method.

```
this.rolesArr.push(...res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `Object.entries` for getting the label and value and then with the function `reduce` build the desired output.

```js
let obj = {  1: "System Admin",  2: "Internal Account Manager",  3: "CAT Manager",  4: "HR Admin",  5: "HR Manager",  6: "HR Recruiter",  7: "Candidate",  8: "Operations administrator"},
    result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [label, value]) => a.concat({label, value}), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just solving your problem by correcting your provided code so that you can identify what you have done wrong.

```js
var data = { 1: "System Admin", 2: "Internal Account Manager", 3: "CAT Manager", 4: "HR Admin", 5: "HR Manager", 6: "HR Recruiter", 7: "Candidate", 8: "Operations administrator" };
    var entries = Object.entries(data);
    var rolesArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        this.rolesArr.push({ label: entries[0][1], value: entries[0][0] })
    }
    console.log(this.rolesArr);
```